# Find the coefficient of $x^1y^7$ in the expansion of $(2x−y)^8$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was doing practice problems for a discrete math class and came across this one which has stumped me. I know that if the problem was "Find the coefficient of x^1y^7 in the expansion of $(x−y)^8$" the answer is $C(8,7)$ but i can't figure out this one.

Comment: The coefficient is actually $-16 = -2\cdot C(8,7)$ as opposed to $8 = C(8,7)$. Please see the ansewr below for the more general case.

Answer (score 2):

Using the binomial theorem $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} x^i y^{n-i}$$ we have the following:

$$(2x-y)^8=\sum_{i=0}^8 \binom{8}{i} (2x)^i (-y)^{8-i}=\sum_{i=0}^8 \binom{8}{i} 2^i (-1)^{8-i}x^i y^{8-i}$$

That means that the coefficient of $x^iy^{8-i}$ is $\binom{8}{i} 2^i(-1)^{8-i}$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense then how it was explained to me. thank you very much!